# where is the control visualization code in kibana directory

Tags: elasticsearch, controls, kibana

good morning,
I want to know where the code that refers to the input control visualization of kibana is located. I want to try to modify its operation a bit but I do not see where the code is. can anyone clearify that for me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Input controls visualization code can be found here

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/tree/master/src/core_plugins/input_control_vis